# Is there a hashCode()-like method that can be used for state checking?

Tags: java, state

I thought up a simple and efficient way to combine states with events to make event handling more efficient. My idea of state checking involves State objects that hold reference to mutable variables in an object.

I figure that using a sort of hashCode() for an Object and checking between the two states would be more efficient than iterating over the contents of a State object and comparing to the target state.

Problem is, hashCode() isn't calculated on a per-state basis. Is there some method similar to hashCode() that I can use to compare two states without comparing their contents directly and is cheap on CPU usage?

Edit: I didn't realize hashCode() is on a per-state basis.

Comment: you can optimize the state check by first checking the the hashcode of each field before checking equality.

Comment: @ratchetfreak I'm trying to avoid iteration, and that would require it.

Comment: You may implement `hashCode` so it only depends of the state, it will be still a valid implementation. It *might be undesirable* to use in maps (apart from being mutable) because of a possible high number of collisions. Or maybe I am missing your point.

Comment: @LinkTheProgrammer Lock post?  Are you asking for your post to be put on hold?

Comment: @CandiedOrange I'm asking for the post to die and go to nirvana.

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for `hashCode()` plus a few of the optimizations and overhead associated with it found in other Java classes.

If the hash code is different, than the state is different. That is part of the contract of `hashCode()`.  However, comparing two hash codes generated on the fly for two objects is just as expensive (and possibly more so because the *complete* state must be interrogated in order to create the hash code while `.equals(T object)` can bail out early).

Thus, you go to caching the hash code once you compute it so you only need to generate it once.  However, that 'only generate it once' is 'only generate it once per state'. If the object is an immutable, then you can cache it as soon as it is asked for and return that cached value forever more.  This can be seen in [String.hashCode()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/String.java#1493).  `String` will return the computed hash code if it has already been computed.

However, if the object is mutable, each time you mutate the object you will need to invalidate the hash code that has been generated previously. This is where the overhead comes in.

All that said, the simple and understandable thing to do that doesn't add complexity to your code is to use `equals(T object)`. Test the most likely mutated fields first and let the JIT optimizer do its thing.

Comment: Oh, so hashCode() is on a per-state basis? Then how does a HashMap work if the objects change, and the hashCode() becomes different?

Comment: @LinkTheProgrammer you enter the realm of "here be dragons" if you have a HashMap where the key is mutable and mutates. Don't do that.

Comment: Then why does HashMap call hashCode() for objects it contains?

Comment: @LinkTheProgrammer Simple answer: It doesn't. ;-) Using mutable Objects as keys in a HashMap (or elements of a HashSet) is erroneous. If the hashCode changes, the objects can't be equal anymore and therefore cannot be used in such a way.

Comment: @LinkTheProgrammer it calls it on insert to figure out what bucket to put it in.  It calls it when it has to resize the underlying array and rehash all the keys. It calls it on the key when it looks up. If the inserted key's hashCode changes between when it was inserted or rehashed and when something is trying to look it up, you won't find it. To be safe, you shouldn't use mutable objects as HashMap keys.

Comment: @LinkTheProgrammer: I encourage you to read Eric Lippert's [Guidelines and rules for GetHashCode](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/28/guidelines-and-rules-for-gethashcode.aspx).  It was written from the perspective of C#, but the guidelines are basically the same.

Comment: HashMap line 156: "Tree bins (i.e., bins whose elements are all TreeNodes) are ordered primarily by hashCode,..."

Comment: @LinkTheProgrammer when inserted, the hashCode is used. If it changes after that, Bad Things happen. An underlying hashtable of size 11 will hash 12 and 23 to the same bucket. The elements in that bucket are an ordered TreeMap by hash value (because the only common comparable thing is hashCode - the objects may be of different types and not mutually comparable). (The quote is from the [Java 8 implementation](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/HashMap.java#HashMap))

Comment: ... *still* don't change the thing that is being used to look up once it is inserted into a structure that depends on that look up value not changing. That is a key underlying assumption for all ordered structures (Trees, ordered lists, etc...) - and the hash map, under the covers, is ordered by hashcode.

Comment: @MichaelT Well when you put it that way... `equals()` seems to be the most efficient route. I am using Fork/Join... though I wonder: does `equals()` effectively return `true` if two _unique and different_ objects contain the same internal state? I would rather not iterate each held variable and do `equals()` on all of them, but rather compare the actual state object.

Comment: @LinkTheProgrammer that really depends on how equals is implemented and how complex the object is. Typically, it is rather fast.

Comment: Then `hashCode()` + Fork/Join seem like the most reliable choice. The way you put it, equals doesn't sound very consistent...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24386/discussion-between-link-theprogrammer-and-michaelt).

Comment: @LinkTheProgrammer I would encourage you to head to The Whiteboard via [chat] rather than a specific chat room for this question. There are others in there who can also help too.

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear what you're looking for.
But if you want to detect state change events without laborious comparison it's a well proven pattern to use a version indicator. That can be as simple as a counter that is incremented each time any relevant data is modified.

Depending on the purpose you might encounter one of two classes of problems.
First is the AA problem. The set method of property with the value A is called with the value A. A naive implementation records a change (by incrementing the version counter) but nothing actually changed.
Second is the ABA or ABC problem. If a set method is called twice before a 'monitor mechanism' visits the object again it will miss state B and may (in the ABA case) entirely miss that a change 'really' occurred.

That might not matter. It might make the program slightly less efficient (causing say screen updates that in fact change nothing) or worse break logic.

Comment: This incrementing based on state change is a good idea for non-realtime programs I would suppose. I would prefer a way to do so on the fly. In my case, every nanosecond counts. And proven by all those problems which can be encountered due to race conditions, that's the last problem I need and overly complex.

Comment: Unless you're going to emit a message (to a monitor) when state changes I would say for nanosecond counts of 'did something here just change' then a version counter is indicated (not contra-indicated). It's partly a matter of whether you need to respond to all changes or just know if there were changes since your last visit.

Comment: Well, events are on a "last-visit" basis.

Comment: Then this is a scenario where a version counter might apply.

Comment: Would it help to say the thing I am creating this for is an API that works for the realtime game Minecraft?

Comment: I would help if you told us more about what you're trying to implement. I would say most real time applications end up needing to notify some monitor that they've changed rather than wait for a recurring laborious sweep.

Comment: I'm starting to think avoiding iteration is futile.

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to do. Minecraft avoids some comprehensive iteration by making some events random so it can sample.

Comment: @LinkTheProgrammer before you give up on avoiding iteration let me ask, do you know how the observer pattern works?

Comment: @CandiedOrange why, of course :)

Comment: @LinkTheProgrammer Then help me understand, why bother recalculating hashcodes when properly encapsulated classes could simply notify their observers when something changes their state?

Comment: @CandiedOrange Because that isn't the purpose of this implementation. The State implementation doesn't have to be event based. And that could cause a lot of overhead if it notifies a List of Observers every tick.

Comment: @CandiedOrange I want to be able to check for the state of an object at any arbitrary time. Not notify an observer when the state changes. The effect should be passive.

Comment: @LinkTheProgrammer how passive is passive?  The observer pattern is flexible enough to let you dump a reference to every updated object in a queue that you can process (inspect state) whenever you like, as passively as you like.  Thus avoiding iterating over things that haven't changed.  When you process and when you clear the queue are completely decoupled from when state changes.  If, rather than passive, you decide to be aggressive about clearing the queue, look into the producer consumer pattern.